# Intercept and alter a site's javascript using greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Suppose there is a site that includes an external .js file in an html script tag like so:

```
<script src="somescript.js">
```

I want greasemonkey to intercept each of such scripts, and alter some of the values in them before they execute. For example, I want to change all occurrences of the value "400" to "300" within them, then continue to load the page as if the scripts used those values instead of the original ones. Currently I'm using the following code in greasemonkey:

```
function replaceTargetJavascript (scriptNode) {
    var scriptSrc   = scriptNode.textContent;
    scriptSrc       = scriptSrc.replace (
        /'400'/,
        "'300'"
    );

    addJS_Node (scriptSrc);
}

document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", function(e) {

    checkForBadJavascripts ( [
        [false, /'400'/, replaceTargetJavascript]
    ] );
}, true);
```

Which according to my sources is the right way to do it, but it is not working. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: That's not how you use [checkForBadJavascripts](https://gist.github.com/2620135).  (EG, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11201555/331508).) ... Also you cannot do on-the-fly edits of the *contents* of scripts loaded via `<script src="...`.  You must block the scripts, then fetch them later with `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, then edit them, then insert script nodes.

Comment: Would you be willing to write up how to do what you just described? Pretty please?

Comment: Cool, I actually solved it... I'll post the solution as an answer soon.

Comment: @Joey - Did you ever post your solution or find any good notes?

Comment: Just use mutation observer. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632475/watch-for-element-creation-in-greasemonkey-script

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Old question, but I needed to do this recently.
Here's how I did it using GreaseMonkey.

You add the beforescriptexecute listener, and wait for your target script to be loaded, checking the src tag to identify the correct script.

Then you stop that script from loading and get the script source yourself using GM_xmlhttpRequest.

Then you are free to modify the script as you please and insert it back into the DOM.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   Test
// @description TEST
// @include     http://the.website.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addScript(text) {
    text = text.replace(/replaceThis();/g, "");
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = "text/javascript";
    newScript.textContent = text;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(newScript);
}

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {
    src = e.target.src;
    if (src.search(/script_to_modify\.js/) != -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();        
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: "GET",
            url: e.target.src,
            onload: function(response) {
                addScript(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, this is the right way to do it. Almost forgot I ever asked this question!

Comment: I know, I always feel obliged to answer old unanswered questions like this that I come across!
https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: This is not a standard feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute

Comment: We should be able to do this cross-browser with `MutationObserver`, but that doesn't seem to work with GM for some reason... I gave up :-(

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I needed to do this recently and the accepted answer uses the non-standard-feature `beforescriptexecute`.

It's basically the same as the accepted answer but using the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as comments alluded to, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518023/1214236)  for a duplicate question.

```js
new MutationObserver(async (mutations, observer) => {
    let oldScript = mutations
        .flatMap(e => [...e.addedNodes])
        .filter(e => e.tagName == 'SCRIPT')
        .find(e => e.src.match(/old-script.js/))

    if (oldScript) {
        observer.disconnect()
        oldScript.remove()

        let text = await fetch(oldScript.src).then(e => e.text())
            .then(e => e.replace(/hijack-part/g, "profit"))

        let newScript = document.createElement('script')
        newScript.type = 'module' // or text/javascript depending on what you hijack
        newScript.textContent = text
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(newScript)
    }
}).observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
})
```

I'm not 100% sure in what order things happen regarding mutations and script loading/executing though. So I don't know if there are corner cases where the script has already been executed before the observer gets mutation. AFAICT the `MutationObserver` is only an observer and can't strictly prevent nodes being added, just remove them immediately.

In my case it works though.

Comment: this worked immediately perfectly to inject a new script! thanks a lot