# Edit javascript on browser side

Tags: javascript, browser

For integration purpose I use javascript file from other provider. I add it to my site in next way

```
    var other = document.createElement('script');
    other.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    other.async = true;
    other.src = SOME_URL_ON_OTHER_DOMAIN;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(other);
```

Now I would like to change it content. Could I do this myself on browser side without changing on javascript provider side? It would be fine it will be not cross browser solution.

Comment: Is there anything specific that you want to change in its content? Maybe a variable value or a function's behavior?

Comment: @LcSalazar I need to change content of some functions. Would be nice to work with it as with strings.

Comment: No, you cannot change the content of an arbitrary script that you don't control. And you can access the content of the script on a different domain due to SOP. Monkeypatching the objects that the script created is possible, though (especially if they're global).

Comment: You can redefine variables, functions etc, that exist in the remote script. For example if there's a function named "myFunction" you can do something like window["myFunction"] = function(){}

Comment: For anyone coming across here https://stackoverflow.com/q/22141205/1214236 might also be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to watch and wait for the remote file to be loaded. Once it's loaded you can redefine functions. For example something like this should get you started:

```
redefineRemoteFunctions = setInterval( function() {
    if ( typeof window["remoteFunction"] == "function" ) {
        // looks like the remote library has been loaded, we can now redefine the functions
        window["remoteFunction"] = function( ) {
            // do whatever you want here
        };
        clearInterval(redefineRemoteFunctions);
    }
}, 100 );
```

Comment: Doesn't completely solve the original question. But seems as the best available option.

Comment: Why are you once using `remoteFunction` and once `window["remoteFunction"]`?

Comment: I guess they should both be window["remoteFunction"], thanks @Bergi I'll update it