# Replace Execution Of Javascript File Loaded From Website With My Own

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, greasemonkey, adblock

There is a counter on website **http://example.com/website**. This counter is executed from javascript file that is downloaded to computer.

It contains a function that updates a page after the counter hits 0 seconds. This javascript is loaded from **http://example.com/scripts/timer.js** and this load is called from **http://example.com/website** page within **html** like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/timer.js"></script>`

The goal is to change the time of the counter.
So I tried the following using **Firefox**, **GreaseMonkey** and **AdBlockPlus** plugins:

1. Downloading the original **timer.js** file and changing it **(this works ok)**.
2. Blocking execution of original "timer.js" with **AdBlockPlus** plugin  **(this works ok)**.
3. Executing edited **timer.js** from my computer using **GreaseMonkey** plugin by replacing the source of the script within html of **http://example.com/websites** **(this doesn't work)**.

I've already tried solutions provided previously here [Greasemonkey - replace javascript src to load custom JS instead the one of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072702/greasemonkey-replace-javascript-src-to-load-custom-js-instead-the-one-of-the-p) and here 
[Stop execution of Javascript function (client side) or tweak it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972038/stop-execution-of-javascript-function-client-side-or-tweak-it) but for some reasons they doesn't work at all. The timer counter doesn't show up on the webpage and I've spent a day to figure out how to make it work.

Maybe there is easier solution by using Firefox? If I understand correctly the main idea is right.

Thank You for Your help!

Comment: @wOxxOm it doesn't use Date. I've already changed the file correctly but I can't load it on a webpage while the original file is blocked

Comment: It is possible to do this (at least with tampermonkey, so I'm assuming Greasemonkey too) see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22141205/1214236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I've found only a solution to download and install **Fiddler** web debugging proxy and change **Firefox** proxy settings to those specified in Fiddler. To execute edited file I've used Fiddler's **rule to autorespond** with local file when there is a request to specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

As you can said, can use of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) web debugging proxy.

Firstly set proxy on browser: `127.0.0.1:8888` to pass traffic through `Fiedler`.

###### Solution #1:

Then from `AutoResponder` tab set `http://example.com/scripts/timer.js` address to `http://example.com/scripts/timer_2.js` new address as below image:

[image]

###### Solution #2:

Or another way can you can use `QuickExec` command line in bottom of window, and this command:

```
urlreplace timer.js timer_2.js
```

In this way, all addresses containing the phrase `timer.js` to `timer_2.js` will be replaced and new addresses will be loaded.

###### Solution #3:

Alternatively, type in the command line:

```
bpa http://example.com/scripts/timer.js
```

[image]

with do this, put a break point on the response.
You can then modify the content of the page before it reaches the browser.